# Trying to understand how the first stage of this SAR ADC works

Tags: adc

Before I go to the actual problem I want to tell that the only ADC architecture I ever analyzed was the conventional SAR ADC:

[image]

Now I'm trying to understand this one:

[image]

Taken from the article "A 12-Bit, 300-MS/s Single-Channel Pipelined-SAR ADC With an Open-Loop MDAC"

It's said this in the article:

[image]

So first step should be to sample the input. Connect VCM to the top plates and Vinp/Vinn to the bottom plates and for all I understood those comparators are there just to speed things up so it shouldn't be different from the circuit above that has just one comparator.

In this circuit there's something called split-capacitors that have VrefP and vRefN connected to them. I don't really understand their purpose and what should I do with them.

Given that this is a Sar how does the second step, comparing Vcp-vCn work? I'm trying to relate this to the first circuit but I can't understand.

Also, why is VrefP and vRefN connected twice to the same capacitor?